# Primefaces DataGrid initialize the records of the selected page

Tags: primefaces, datagrid

I'm using a datagrid to load some products (more than 10,000), but the page is loading really slow.

Does Primefaces has the behaviour of jqgrid to load just the records of the selected page? How can I change a datagrid to have this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: I also need pagination, so that's why I can't replace it with datascroller

Comment: That is called dataTable I think... and if the docs of PF does not mention anything in this regard for datagrid, it is not there

Comment: I also need to have the thumbnail aspect, so I need to keep the datagrid component...

Comment: I think you should use lazy behavior. Pls check link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42130477/1698962